# PHP Shopping cart without login - cookies vs sessions vs both?

Tags: php, session, cookies, shopping-cart

It's a php based web store without user logins because all of the payments are handled via paypal.  My question is what would you guys suggest for the shopping cart - cookies, sessions, or both?  I'm not too concerned with the longevity of the shopping cart's contents be I'd like for the user to be able to click around and do a few things before they commit the order.  I'm leaning towards sessions because some people may still disable cookies on their machines.

Comment: You should manage authentication details etc in sessions to be safe and details like products purchased recently can be kept in cookies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP sessions use a cookie with the session id to track the user. I would go with sessions since it will handle all of the identification for you and make things easier and more transparent.

It is also possible to use sessions with no cookies and it will pass the session id around in the URL.  That in some cases can be a security risk, but perhaps not so much in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

By default, PHP sets a cookie on the visitor's browser to know which session id to use anyway, so the only real difference between the three options in the end would be how much data gets sent up to your server during the request.

That being said, you can also use sessions without cookies by making sure to add `?session_id={session_id();}` to all of your internal links and the following to the beginning of every page:

```
 if (isset($_GET ['session_id'])
   session_id($_GET ['session_id'])

 session_start();
```

So, recommend using sessions.